# Show/hide view after recyclerview notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a layout which contains the following views:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rvChat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/stickersContainer"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

 <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ibChatSmile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="6"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/smile" />

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/stickersContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tbStickers"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/stickersPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/tbStickers"
android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

stickersContainer - is layout which I want to show/hide. Recyclerview contains chat messages and ImageButton shows/hides stickersContainer. As you see there are tabLayout and ViewPager in stickersContainer.

To ViewPager I load this fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.oopslab.outarguemechat.Fragments.Stickers.StickersContainerFragment">

<GridView
android:id="@+id/gvStickersContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:numColumns="3" />
```

for hiding/showing layout I use setVisibility() function;
and it seems all works well until I called notifyDataSetChanged() for recyclerview.

when I press a hide button it hides layout but button and recyclerview stayed at their places.
I'm really confused with this situation. I tried to put layout to the fragment and add/remove it but nothing helps
Also I tried adapter.notifyItemInserted() instead of notifyDataSetChanged() but had the same result

As you might guess, I'm trying to create something like sticker layout(like in viber/telegram/skype, etc.).
May be there is another way to make it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your codes related with controlling visibility.

Comment: I simply change visibility of tabLayout and viewPager from gone to visible by setVisibility(). Like tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I've encountered this strange behavior as well. What seemed to be your issue?